# Install Microsoft Java VM on Windows 7 + IE8

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, digital-signature, security-policy

I cannot install **Microsoft** Java VM on Windows 7 and IE8.

File xmldso.cab is blocked because it does not have valid digital signature to verify its distributor.

Can you use something like group policy to by-pass signature verification?

Comment: What have you tried already?  What version of the "Java VM" are you trying to install exactly?

Comment: It is Microsoft VM build 3805. Not SUN Java VM. This is the download link:
http://www.netvigator.com/netvigator/smn/download/msjavx86.exe

Comment: Finally, I fix this by using Windows XP mode